# interpreting output of attribute selection in weka

Tags: weka

I have got

```
=== Attribute selection 10 fold cross-validation seed: 2 ===

number of folds (%)  attribute

          10(100 %)   1 H0_D0 
          10(100 %)   3 Ar
           0(  0 %)   4 LT_LH
           0(  0 %)   5 tan_y_2
          10(100 %)   6 DT_D0
           0(  0 %)   7 LH_DT
```

Could you please interpret this result?

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of feature selection algorithms in weka.
The output you added is probably the output of the CFS (`CfsSubsetEval`) algorithm.

In simple words this algorithm is designed to find a subset of features that "work well together". The output that you see is the number of folds in which each feature was selected (if you don't know what are these folds, read about k-fold cross validation).
More specifically: `HO_DO`, `Ar` and `DT_DO` were selected in all of the 10 folds while the other features were never selected.

Other algorithms such as `InfoGainAttributeEval` have other output. Their output is the average score each feature received (in most cases, the higher the better) and it's STD value.

Good luck.